# Can Sqlite's AUTOINCREMENT/Primary Key be started at a number other than 1?

Tags: sqlite

I would like to start different tables off at different values for their primary keys during testing to verify I don't have any bugs in my code. Is this possible in Sqlite?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [documented](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html), the last value of an AUTOINCREMENT column is stored in the internal [sqlite_sequence table](http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#seqtab), where it can be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that.

The simplest way is probably just to insert a row, and specify the the number. If I wanted to start with 1000, I might do something like this.

```
sqlite> create table test (test_id integer primary key, s char(1));
sqlite> insert into test values (999, 'a');
sqlite> insert into test (s) values ('b');
sqlite> select * from test;
999|a
1000|b
```

After you've inserted the "first" row (test_id is 1000), you can delete the "seed" row (test_id is 999).